# htaccess, auth to use index.php but allow some folder without any auth

Tags: php, .htaccess, authentication

First time I post something here, usually I find what I need, I hope you could help me and maybe it'll help others too.

I have a hand made mvc (only php/html/js/bootstrap) and I need to restrict few access but allow others, I tried few answers but nothing seems to work in my case.

Here is my directory structure :

[Directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6lMr.png)

So here is my problem, I want people to auth to allow access to index.php and all of the directories. This part is fine and very easy to setup. But I also need to allow them to access 3 folders without any auth ("/datas", "/datasProd" and also "/jeux"). 
I tried to add some htaccess in those folders where i wrote this in order to allow everyone :

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
```

And here is my root htaccess

```
<Files index.php>

AuthUserFile "<path to my htpasswd>"
AuthName "Accès Restreint"
AuthType basic
require valid-user

</Files>

Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
```

With this config I must auth to access index.php but I must auth too if I want to access the content of datas, datasProd, and jeux. I think the problem come from my root htaccess but I can't find out what's going wrong :/

I tried to be as clear as possible but ask me if you need more information about my setup.

Thanks for help ! and sorry for my english...

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution, easier than I though,

In my main htaccess, I got :

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName 'Acces Admin'
AuthUserFile "/home/www/fabrique/www/jeuxjuniorAugustins/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
```

And in each folders I want to allow access i added this small htaccess file

```
Satisfy any
```

I was just missing the correct syntax. 
Now I must log on to access index.php and all folders but not for the ones where I put the small htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

hello set en environment variable for the requests you what to allow:
here an example for the folder "permitted"

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI 'permitted' allow

AuthType Basic
AuthName 'dev access'
AuthUserFile /var/www/htdocs/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

Allow from env=allow
Deny from all
Satisfy any
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I tried it, still not working :/ no more auth required..

Comment: hi I tried this myself and it works, http://foo.bar/ -> login required, http://foo.bar/permitted/ -> no login, http://foo.bar/stuff/ -> login required, you must have not implemented it corectly